# How does [:] work in python?

Tags: python, copy

It copies a list right? but in the code I'm looking at its `x = x[:]` which I don't understand. How can both copies be called the same thing?

Comment: It's the same as if you have `a = a + 1`. First `a + 1` is evaluated and the result is overriding the current value of `a`. Though, `x = x[:]` seems unnecessary, unless `x` is a function parameter and you want to enforce a copy of the argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The right is evaluated first, placed into a temporary variable, and x is re-assigned to the temp variable. You never see it, of course.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question "How does [:] work in python?" is a bit tricky in the context of this particular expression by itself

```
x = x[:]
```

which isn't that likely to occur as it's really like saying `a = a`.

You are more likely to see something like

```
a = x[:]
```

which in simple words makes a copy of the list referred to by `x` and assigns it to `a`.

If you simply did

```
a = x
```

both variables would refer to the same location, and any change to either of the variables would be reflected in both.

Here is what happens if you don't use the colon notation, e.g., `a = x`:

```
In [31]: x = range(5)
In [32]: a = x

In [33]: a
Out[33]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

In [34]: x
Out[34]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

In [35]: a[3] = 99    # I am making a change in a

In [36]: a
Out[36]: [0, 1, 2, 99, 4]

In [37]: x
Out[37]: [0, 1, 2, 99, 4]   # but x changes too!
```

Compare this with `a = x[:]`

```
In [38]: x = range(5)
In [39]: a = x[:]

In [40]: a
Out[40]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

In [41]: x
Out[41]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

In [42]: a[3] = -99    

In [43]: a
Out[43]: [0, 1, 2, -99, 4]  # a changes

In [44]: x
Out[44]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]    # x does not change
```

Note: @gnibbler provides a short and complete example (below in the
comments) where you might encounter `x = x[:]` and in that context
that assignment would serve a useful purpose (though we don't know in what context you came across this originally).

Comment: I think [Felix's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273186/how-does-work-in-python#comment13212644_10273186) hits the nail on the head _why_ this would be done.

Comment: @sarnold good point .. just saw it too. I guess I went by the question itself "how does [:] work in python".

Comment: You'd totally do x = x[:] to dup an existing list

Comment: @Richo Can you provide an example, I'm not doubting you, but I can't come up with a good one for this.

Comment: @Jeff I guess without knowing the whole context (none was provided) it's difficult to know, and we can always imagine various scenarios. But looking at `x = x[:]` by itself *without* any additional information seems a bit like `a = a`, no? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: for `def f(x): x=x[:] #make a copy of the list so the function can modify it locally` this type of usage is fairly common

Comment: @gnibbler That is a great simple and complete example and clarifies the comment by Felix above too. Thanks for sharing this.

Comment: @Levon @gnibbler's example is a good case. Note this creates a new list with the same elements as the original; `x=x[:]; x[1].append("newitem")` will still have sideeffects/

Comment: @Richo, yes it only makes a shallow copy